# Moving Average Two Index Python

Tags: python, indexing, moving-average

Good afternoon,

I am trying to get the moving average (3Months) of a range of products and categories (cat.).

```
Example = pd.DataFrame(
            {'Date':['2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-04-01','2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-04-01','2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-04-01'], 
             'Store':['1', '1','1','1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2',],
             'Cat':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1],
             'Sales':[3,3,4,1,7,3,2,0,4,2,9,1],}
)

Example = Example.set_index(["Store", "Cat"]).fillna(False)
Example
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mdL1.png)

So you get the list. I have tried to get for Store 1 and Cat. 1 but I dont know how to do in bulce automatically.

```
Example_med = Example.query(" Store == '1' and Cat == 1")
Example_med["M3"] = Example_med.Sales.rolling(window=3).mean()
Example_med
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYNfA.png)

Could you help me please. May it easy but I am starting learning python and I havent found anything on the web.

Thank you!

Comment: Please dont use images to paste the output. Take time to copy it as text and you will be more likely to receive help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I meant I am trying to get the moving average (3Months) of the Sales for a range of stores and categories (cat.).